# Unable to Edit the Session in 'Hermes JMS'

Tags: jms, soapui, hermes-jms

I am trying to configure JMS through SOAPUI Open Source. 
I have created a 'Session' and added 'Provider' (ActiveMQ) and 'Connection Factory'. When I am trying to Add 'Properties', the Edit button corresponding to the session doesn't work. 
I am following the link 'https://www.soapui.org/documentation/jms/config.html' to configure JMS. 
Please help.

Config File:

Comment: Have you tried making changes into `hermes-config.xml` directly to see if you could proceed?

Comment: @Rao- I have no idea about hermes-config.xml and the changes required in this file. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Check soapui's documentation please - https://www.soapui.org/documentation/jms/config.html

Comment: @Rao- I am following the same link and stuck at a point where properties needs to be added. Could you please suggest what changes can be done in 'hermes-config.xml' to make it work.

Comment: I don't know what properties you need. What is the issue to edit the file?

Comment: I am able to go till step 'Add Factory Class' and when I try to add 'Properties', the Edit button doesn't work. The edit window is not opening.

Comment: Are you able to locate the hermes-config.xml file? Can you try open it in a text editor?

Comment: yes, I am able to locate the hermes-config.xml file and same is opened in editor.

Comment: Can't you be able to add the properties accordingly? or attach the file if possible?

Comment: @Rao- are you able to see the Config file text in the question section. I am unable to attach the file.

Comment: No, can't. Probably add file here and send link - https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @Rao- Please refer to the link 'https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3a89ef08c26338dae438cbc54a85568d'.

Comment: Depending on your use case, your could be interested in [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox) which is simpler to use and configure

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when using with ActiveMQ 5.15.2
Read somewhere on the web that it is because incompatible jar files in newer ActiveMQ version. Then I downloaded ActiveMQ version 5.3.2 and it solved this issue.